# How to use `attr` when not on `content` property

Tags: css

It is possible to get css to use the value of an attribute in the `content` property (useful in tool-tips, e.g.):

```css
span:hover:after {
  content:attr(tip);
}
```

```html
<span tip=" and behold my glory">Hover on me</span>
```

I am attempting to use this to position elements absolutely. The idea being that in my html I specify different x,y positions as data-attributes that the css picks the appropriate attribute using media queries, e.g.:

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
}

span {
  display:block;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background:blue;
  position:absolute;
  /* SMall screen - show in top corner */
  top: attr(data-sm-x);
  left: attr(data-sm-y);
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  span {
    /* MeDium screen - show in middle of parent */
    top: attr(data-md-x);
    left: attr(data-md-y);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span data-sm-x="10" data-sm-y="10" data-md-x="50" data-md-y="50"></span>
</div>
```

The expected result is to have the blue square in the top corner on small screens, and in the middle of the red square on larger screens, but this does not work.

How do I get the `attr` function to work on non-content properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage in other properties than content is experimental: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr

Comment: ...and not yet supported in any major browser.